# Restore right-click menu on taskbar icon in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, context-menu

### SCENARIO

---

I've been customizing a **[Windows 10 TH2](http://www.winbeta.org/news/use-microsofts-media-creation-tool-grab-windows-10-november-update)** ISO image using the **[WinToolkit](http://www.wincert.net/forum/files/file/5-win-toolkit/)** application, and manually using **[DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825236.aspx)** to remove features and packages from the mounted **[Install.wim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format)** image, I also removed from the **[WinSXS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly)** directory specific unrequired files for my needs on which I'm not interested and are safe to be removed, like for example a bunch of ***TTC*** and ***TTF*** font files, ***Skype***, ***OneDrive*** and ***WMP*** file references, ***Metro*** Apps, drivers, shortcuts, etc.

After I'd customized the ***WIM*** image, I installed the ***O.S.*** on a virtual machine (**[VMWare Workstation](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation)**), and I was working for weeks on that ***V.M.*** by installing custom apps, 3rd party themes, and reducing a little bit more the space on disk because my intention was to [capture the modified partition with **DISM**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825072.aspx) with all the customizations applied to generate a new ***Install.wim*** so in that way I can burn a ***Windows 10 ISO*** with all my programs installed by default and the system personalizations I did.

- To clarify:

  I'm not a ***Windows*** gurú, but I consider that thanks to the experience of years I have decent, good, almost advanced knowledges in general, about the ***Windows*** filesystem.

  This is not the first time that I realize this task, I've successfully done the same work with ***Windows 8/8.1*** and ***Windows 7*** in the past. More than that, currently I'm on a ***Windows 8.1*** from 2 years ago modified by me with the same methodology with a lot of things deleted (some safe, some unsafe) and without issues of any sort.

### PROBLEM

---

The problem I discovered is that due to the modifications I did, when I do right-click on a taskbar icon, this menu doesn't appears:

[image]

( I mean the context-menu of the image with pinned folders and "*Close window*" item, etc, the entire context-menu. )

Instead of that menu, nothing is shown, just nothing happens when I do right-click on a taskbar icon, however, the thumbnail preview and the other cms (like the start button cm) are working.

As I said, I was working for weeks on the ***V.M.*** customizing my ***Windows 10***, and I discovered this annonying issue at the last day of all this work, so "rolling back" to waste a couple of weeks again is not an option for me.

### QUESTION

---

I would like to ask for advanced users in Windows debugging to help me debug what is happening when the user do right-click on a taskbar icon to discover what is the cause of the missing context-menu. I don't know if maybe apps like ***[Process Monitor from SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx)*** or **[Spy Studio from Nektra](http://www.nektra.com/products/spystudio-api-monitor/download/)** could help me to discover and fix the issue by examining windows calls and events, I need orientation in this way or someone who could do it for me.

Or I ask for what files or packages or registry values or dependencies in general are required to that contextmenu to be shown, then knowing that maybe I could restore/copy the missing things from a working ***O.S.*** to the non-working ***O.S.***.

Please note that I could try any thing with any risk of ***O.S.*** corruption because I work with snapshots in the ***V.M.*** that I can restore to a previous ***O.S.*** state if a possible solution fails.

### RESEARCH

---

( To avoid confusions, I will name "**non-working O.S.**" the customized ***O.S.*** on the ***V.M.*** that has the missing context-menu, and "**working O.S.**" the ***O.S.*** on the ***V.M.*** that has the context-menu working )

After I discovered this problem, I generated a ***Windows 10*** ISO with ***WinToolkit*** without this annonying issue, then I've installed that "working" ***O.S.***, in a new Virtual Machine and I was trying a couple of basic possible solutions, like these ones:

- Copy the entire contents of **WinSXS** folder (and all the other system folders like program files, appdata, etc) from the "working" ***O.S.*** to the non-working ***O.S.***, this way I tried to restore missing deleted files of the non-working ***O.S.*** that maybe were required for the context-menu to be shown.

  Unafortunately this methodology didn't solved anything.
- Export all the registry keys of all registry root keys from the "working" ***O.S.*** to the customized ***O.S.***

  I was unable to import the **HKCU** root due to registry user-permissions, but I imported the **HKCR**, **HKU**, and **HKLM** (not all keys, registry user-permissions again), but the problem was not solved.
- I'd enabled and ran all the Windows services of the non-working O.S.

  This didn't solved the nothing.
- On the non-working ***O.S.*** I tried desesperatelly the ***[Windos Repair](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html)*** application, also ***[CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)*** and ***[Wise Registry Cleaner](http://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-registry-cleaner.html)***.
- I'd uninstalled all the custom apps, codecs, etc of the non-working ***O.S.***, I can completely discard and ensure is not a problem of any 3rd party program.
- These are the system files that I removed in the non-working ***O.S.***:

  - ***[Windows 10 TH2 filelist.txt](https://www.zerobin.net/?190452fe5154530e#Ff3le2JXYP5BvS8Cx0JK2L+4XbmGPlcIedd5hezuMJM=)***

    But remember that in a step above I mentioned that I did an entire copy from the directories of the "working" ***O.S.*** to the non-working ***O.S.*** to restore the missing files to try determine if a missing file was the cause of the context-menu problem...
- This is the **WinToolkit**'s configuration profile that I used to generate a ***Windows 10 TH2 ISO*** (that causes the MISSING context-menu by default):

  - ***[Windows 10 TH2 Lite.ini](http://pastebin.com/Y3Atmsru)***
- In the "working" ***O.S.***, with ***[WIM Registry Tweak Tool](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152688-win6x-registry-tweak/)*** pointing to "C:\" root I started to [remove all the packages using ***DISM***](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824838.aspx) that I removed in the non-working ***O.S.*** with the intention to try determine, at least, if the missing context-menu was caused by a missing package, which could be one of these:

  ```
  Adobe-Flash-For-Windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Media-FaceAnalysis-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Media-FaceAnalysis-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Media-FaceAnalysis-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Media-FaceAnalysis-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor-Core-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor-Core-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor-vm-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor-vm-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Clients-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Clients-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell-Package-net~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell-Package-net~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Offline-Common-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Offline-Common-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Offline-Common-vm-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Offline-Common-vm-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Offline-Core-Group-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Offline-Core-Group-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Online-Services-Core-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Online-Services-Core-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Online-Services-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Online-Services-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Online-Services-vm-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Online-Services-vm-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Package-ds-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Package-minkernel-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Package-net~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Package-net~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Package-termsrv-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Package-termsrv-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Server-Drivers-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Server-Drivers-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Services-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Services-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-AllowTelemetry-Reduced-Default-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-AppRuntime-xbox-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-AppRuntime-xbox-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-ds-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-ds-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-FaceRecognition-ds-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-FaceRecognition-ds-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-FaceRecognition-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-FaceRecognition-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-FaceRecognition-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-FaceRecognition-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-Fingerprint-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-Fingerprint-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-Fingerprint-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-Fingerprint-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-WOW64-ds-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-WOW64-ds-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Biometrics-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Gaming-Preview-GamesEnumeration-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Gaming-Preview-GamesEnumeration-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Gaming-Preview-GamesEnumeration-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Gaming-Preview-GamesEnumeration-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Gaming-Storage-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Gaming-Storage-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Gaming-Storage-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Gaming-Storage-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Core-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Core-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Core-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Core-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Full-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Full-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Full-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Full-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Full-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Full-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Full-WOW64-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Full-WOW64-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-WOW64-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Maps-WOW64-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Miracast-Common-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Miracast-Common-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Miracast-Transmitter-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Miracast-Transmitter-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Miracast-Transmitter-shell-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Miracast-Transmitter-shell-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Miracast-Transmitter-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Miracast-Transmitter-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Media-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Media-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Media-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Media-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-multimedia-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-multimedia-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-WOW64-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-WOW64-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-WOW64-multimedia-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-WOW64-multimedia-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingReceiver-Platform-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Media-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Media-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Media-multimedia-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Media-multimedia-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Media-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Media-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Media-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Media-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-MiracastView-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-MiracastView-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Platform-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Platform-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Platform-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-Multimedia-CastingTransmitter-Platform-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-enduser-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-enduser-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-shell-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-shell-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-WOW64-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-WOW64-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-WOW64-enduser-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-WOW64-enduser-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-WOW64-shell-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-OneCore-SpeechComponents-WOW64-shell-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Virtualization-Client-Interop-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Client-Drivers-xbox-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Client-Drivers-xbox-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-COM-MSMQ-package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Cortana-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Cortana-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Cortana-PAL-Desktop-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client-Package-admin~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client-Package-admin~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  microsoft-windows-directoryservices-adam-snapins-package-admin~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  microsoft-windows-directoryservices-adam-snapins-package-admin~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Help-ClientUA-Enterprise-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Help-ClientUA-Enterprise-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Help-ClientUA-Professional-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Help-ClientUA-Professional-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Handwriting-es-es-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-OCR-es-es-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Speech-es-es-enduser-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Speech-es-es-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Speech-es-es-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Speech-es-es-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-TextToSpeech-es-es-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-TextToSpeech-es-es-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-multimedia-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-multimedia-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-WOW64-multimedia-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-WOW64-multimedia-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-WOW64-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Media-Streaming-WOW64-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-MiracastView-AppX-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-MiracastView-AppX-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-MSMQ-Client-Home-Premium-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-MSMQ-Client-Home-Premium-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-MSMQ-Client-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-MSMQ-Client-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Printing-LocalPrinting-Enterprise-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-RasRip-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10240.16384
  Microsoft-Windows-RasRip-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384
  Microsoft-Windows-RemoteFX-Graphics-Virtualization-Host-Package-LanguagePack~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-RemoteFX-Graphics-Virtualization-Host-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-RemoteFX-HyperV-Integration-Package-LanguagePack~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-RemoteFX-HyperV-Integration-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-RetailDemo-OfflineContent-Content-es-es-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-RetailDemo-OfflineContent-Content-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-TabletPC-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-TabletPC-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Virtualization-RemoteFX-User-Mode-Transport-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-Virtualization-RemoteFX-User-Mode-Transport-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-WebcamExperience-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Windows-WebcamExperience-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Xbox-GameCallableUI-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Xbox-GameCallableUI-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Xbox-IdentityProvider-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Microsoft-Xbox-IdentityProvider-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Server-Help-Package.ClientEnterprise~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Server-Help-Package.ClientEnterprise~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Server-Help-Package.ClientProfessional~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Server-Help-Package.ClientProfessional~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Windows-Defender-AM-Default-Definitions-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Windows-Defender-Client-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Windows-Defender-Client-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Windows-Defender-Client-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Windows-Defender-Client-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  Windows-Defender-Group-Policy-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.10586.0
  Windows-Defender-Group-Policy-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
  ```

  ...but I was unable to reproduce the issue of the missing context-menu in this way in the "working" ***O.S.***, because after I'd removed all the packages above (and restarted the ***O.S.*** when requested by **DISM**), the context-menu still be shown in the "working" ***O.S.***.
- In the "working" ***O.S.*** I also started to [disable all the features](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744582%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that I disabled in the non-working ***O.S.*** with the intention to try determine, at least, if the missing context-menu was caused by a disabled feature (very improbable, I know, because features are safe to disable by the user), which could be one of these:

  ```
  DirectPlay
  FaxServicesClientPackage
  IIS-ApplicationDevelopment
  IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
  IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics
  IIS-HostableWebCore
  IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic
  IIS-HttpErrors
  IIS-HttpLogging
  IIS-HttpRedirect
  IIS-HttpTracing
  IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility
  IIS-IPSecurity
  IIS-LoggingLibraries
  IIS-ManagementScriptingTools
  IIS-Metabase
  IIS-NetFxExtensibility45
  IIS-NetFxExtensibility
  IIS-Performance
  IIS-RequestFiltering
  IIS-RequestMonitor
  IIS-Security
  IIS-URLAuthorization
  IIS-WebServer
  IIS-WebServerManagementTools
  IIS-WebServerRole
  LegacyComponents
  MSMQ-Container
  MSMQ-DCOMProxy
  MSMQ-HTTP
  MSMQ-Multicast
  MSMQ-Server
  MSMQ-Triggers
  MSRDC-Infrastructure
  NetFx4-AdvSrvs
  NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45
  Printing-Foundation-InternetPrinting-Client
  Printing-Foundation-LPDPrintService
  Printing-Foundation-LPRPortMonitor
  Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Features
  RasRip
  SimpleTCP
  SNMP
  WAS-ConfigurationAPI
  WAS-NetFxEnvironment
  WAS-ProcessModel
  WAS-WindowsActivationService
  WCF-HTTP-Activation45
  WCF-HTTP-Activation
  WCF-MSMQ-Activation45
  WCF-NonHTTP-Activation
  WCF-Pipe-Activation45
  WCF-Services45
  WCF-TCP-Activation45
  WCF-TCP-PortSharing45
  Windows-Identity-Foundation
  WMISnmpProvider
  WorkFolders-Client
  ```

  ...but again (and as expected) I was unable to reproduce the issue of the missing context-menu in this way in the "working" ***O.S.***, because after I'd disabled all the features above, the context-menu still be shown in the "working" ***O.S.***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

The problem that caused the missing contextmenu is because the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch` was deleted.

I manually deleted that key due to customization methodologies about Mozilla Firefox's protocols and DDE, in other versions of Windows I did the same without problem, but in Windows 10 if that key is deleted the taskbar's contextmenu dissapear.

I tested it various times, including in a fresh install of Windows 10 TH2 to ensure the problem is really that, and yes it is, to reproduce the missing contextmenu just delete that key (the entire key including subkeys) and then reset the system, after reset the user will not be able to show the contextmenu when doing right-click on any taskbar icon.

This is a backup from a clean Windows 10 TH2 install of all the registry keys involved in the Mozilla firefox "trick" if someone more needed to restore them:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\DefaultBrowser_NOPUBLISHERID\ActivatableClassId\DefaultBrowser.DefaultBrowserActivatableClass]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="ms-resource:AppDescription"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_1000.10586.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App]
"Vendor"="@{Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_1000.10586.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/resources/PublisherDisplayName}"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_1000.10586.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/Files/Assets/Logo.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_1000.10586.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/resources/PackageDisplayName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_1000.10586.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/resources/PackageDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\Microsoft.AccountsControl_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App]
"Vendor"="@{Microsoft.AccountsControl_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.AccountsControl/Resources/PublisherDisplayName}"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.AccountsControl_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.AccountsControl/Files/Assets/Logo.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.AccountsControl_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.AccountsControl/Resources/DisplayName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.AccountsControl_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.AccountsControl/Resources/Description}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\Microsoft.BioEnrollment_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App]
"Vendor"="@{Microsoft.BioEnrollment_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.BioEnrollment/Resources/PublisherDisplayName}"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.BioEnrollment_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.BioEnrollment/Files/Assets/Logo.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.BioEnrollment_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.BioEnrollment/Resources/AppDisplayName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.BioEnrollment_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.BioEnrollment/Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\Microsoft.LockApp_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\WindowsDefaultLockScreen]
"Vendor"="@{Microsoft.LockApp_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.LockApp/resources/PublisherDisplayName}"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.LockApp_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.LockApp/Files/Assets/Logo.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.LockApp_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.LockApp/resources/AppDisplayName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.LockApp_10.0.10586.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.LockApp/resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare150x150.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App.wwa]
"Vendor"="@{Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost/resources/PublisherDisplayName}"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost/Files/images/Logo.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost/resources/appDisplayName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost/resources/appDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\Microsoft.Windows.SecondaryTileExperience_10.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.Windows.SecondaryTileExperience_10.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.SecondaryTileExperience/Files/Assets/Logo.png}"
"DisplayName"="SecondaryTileExperience"
"Description"="SecondaryTileExperience"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App]
"Vendor"="@{Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost/resources/PublisherDisplayName}"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost/Files/Assets/Logo.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost/resources/AppName/Text}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost/resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\Microsoft.WindowsFeedback_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.WindowsFeedback_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.WindowsFeedback/Files/Assets/FeedbackMedTile.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.WindowsFeedback_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.WindowsFeedback/FeedbackApp.Resources/AppName/Text}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.WindowsFeedback_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.WindowsFeedback/FeedbackApp.Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\Windows.ContactSupport_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Windows.ContactSupport_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Windows.ContactSupport/Files/Assets/MediumTile.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Windows.ContactSupport_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Windows.ContactSupport/Resources/appDisplayName}"
"Description"="@{Windows.ContactSupport_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Windows.ContactSupport/Resources/appDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.File\PackageId\DefaultBrowser_NOPUBLISHERID\ActivatableClassId\DefaultBrowser.DefaultBrowserActivatableClass]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="ms-resource:AppDescription"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.File\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppX88ckeggs6egxxsr4fb2vkabw58058se7.mca]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare150x150.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.File\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppX88ckeggs6egxxsr4fb2vkabw58058se7.mca\CustomProperties]
"SupportedFileTypes"=".xml"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.File\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXbs3yqy036z5crbrjkky4vmbah2kqbz57.mca]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare150x150.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.File\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXbs3yqy036z5crbrjkky4vmbah2kqbz57.mca\CustomProperties]
"SupportedFileTypes"=".svg"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.File\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXre20k58eaa822f0smszc2fbv5y0azn7k.mca]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare150x150.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.File\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXre20k58eaa822f0smszc2fbv5y0azn7k.mca\CustomProperties]
"SupportedFileTypes"=".htm,.html"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.File\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXxat4m5y1bf9ghax409y1vwyatpqea4s8.mca]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare150x150.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.File\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXxat4m5y1bf9ghax409y1vwyatpqea4s8.mca\CustomProperties]
"SupportedFileTypes"=".pdf"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\DefaultBrowser_NOPUBLISHERID\ActivatableClassId\DefaultBrowser.DefaultBrowserActivatableClass]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="ms-resource:AppDescription"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppX9zvsr9qeth9e9a03yr0g7rpdrcrwgn5r.mca]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare150x150.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppX9zvsr9qeth9e9a03yr0g7rpdrcrwgn5r.mca\CustomProperties]
"Name"="http"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXeb42j1vh6rk395pm0vmcx57dxqjhej5d.mca]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare150x150.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXeb42j1vh6rk395pm0vmcx57dxqjhej5d.mca\CustomProperties]
"Name"="microsoft-edge"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXg58n4jqcxjfvb6epaz8mmvfjtq8mhj65.mca]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare150x150.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXg58n4jqcxjfvb6epaz8mmvfjtq8mhj65.mca\CustomProperties]
"Name"="https"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXrwh8xyerps7kqvjsngqmvwenddpt3g5w.mca]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare150x150.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ActivatableClassId\MicrosoftEdge.AppXrwh8xyerps7kqvjsngqmvwenddpt3g5w.mca\CustomProperties]
"Name"="read"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App.AppXe35aa078nkgkdbkbrk5tjm2xds5rwz5q.wwa]
"Vendor"="@{Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost/resources/PublisherDisplayName}"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost/Files/images/Logo.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost/resources/appDisplayName}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost/resources/appDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App.AppXe35aa078nkgkdbkbrk5tjm2xds5rwz5q.wwa\CustomProperties]
"Name"="ms-cxh"
"ReturnResults"="optional"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App.AppXmam9qnhv75mk1bhtxjzdd92dgzf4028g.mca]
"Vendor"="@{Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost/resources/PublisherDisplayName}"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost/Files/Assets/Logo.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost/resources/AppName/Text}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost/resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App.AppXmam9qnhv75mk1bhtxjzdd92dgzf4028g.mca\CustomProperties]
"Name"="ms-actioncenter"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.WindowsFeedback_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App.AppX7eaybq6p4x7d4jgd6w6jk7r5dg6yhmbf.mca]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.WindowsFeedback_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.WindowsFeedback/Files/Assets/FeedbackMedTile.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.WindowsFeedback_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.WindowsFeedback/FeedbackApp.Resources/AppName/Text}"
"Description"="@{Microsoft.WindowsFeedback_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.WindowsFeedback/FeedbackApp.Resources/AppDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.WindowsFeedback_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App.AppX7eaybq6p4x7d4jgd6w6jk7r5dg6yhmbf.mca\CustomProperties]
"Name"="windows-feedback"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Windows.ContactSupport_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App.AppX7xgy3byt9rz3wyrfvsn2j6rss09dtzg0.mca]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Windows.ContactSupport_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Windows.ContactSupport/Files/Assets/MediumTile.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Windows.ContactSupport_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Windows.ContactSupport/Resources/appDisplayName}"
"Description"="@{Windows.ContactSupport_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Windows.ContactSupport/Resources/appDescription}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Windows.ContactSupport_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\App.AppX7xgy3byt9rz3wyrfvsn2j6rss09dtzg0.mca\CustomProperties]
"Name"="ms-contact-support"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Search\PackageId\DefaultBrowser_NOPUBLISHERID\ActivatableClassId\DefaultBrowser.DefaultBrowserActivatableClass]
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Icon"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.png}"
"DisplayName"="@{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}"
"Description"="ms-resource:AppDescription"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\DefaultBrowser_NOPUBLISHERID\ActivatableClassId\DefaultBrowser.DefaultBrowserActivatableClass]
"ActivationType"=dword:00000001
"Server"="DefaultBrowserServer"
"Threading"=dword:00000000
"Activation.Sid"=hex:01,08,00,00,00,00,00,0f,02,00,00,00,3e,44,2b,4d,27,78,ae,\
  96,0d,f1,72,8f,3a,25,9c,7c,93,de,af,33,46,1c,23,99,61,c9,9c,0f

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\DefaultBrowser_NOPUBLISHERID\ActivatableClassId\DefaultBrowser.DefaultBrowserActivatableClass\CustomAttributes]
"AppObject.Aliased"=dword:00000001
"AppObject.EntryPoint"="DefaultBrowser.DefaultBrowserActivatableClass"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\DefaultBrowser_NOPUBLISHERID\Server\DefaultBrowserServer]
"ExePath"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\LaunchWinApp.exe"
"AppUserModelId"="DefaultBrowser_NOPUBLISHERID!Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge"
"Instancing"=dword:00000000
"IdentityType"=dword:00000002
"Permissions"=hex:01,00,04,80,30,00,00,00,3c,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,\
  02,00,1c,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0b,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,\
  00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,0a,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,\
  00,00,21,02,00,00
"ActivatableClasses"=hex(7):44,00,65,00,66,00,61,00,75,00,6c,00,74,00,42,00,72,\
  00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,44,00,65,00,66,00,61,00,75,00,6c,00,\
  74,00,42,00,72,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,41,00,63,00,74,00,69,00,76,\
  00,61,00,74,00,61,00,62,00,6c,00,65,00,43,00,6c,00,61,00,73,00,73,00,00,00,\
  00,00
```

However, for strange it can seems, after deleted those registry keys and reseted the PC, seems that a restoration of those registry keys does not fix the problem, so... if deleted those keys, could be hard to recovery the contextmenu because a registry restoration will not work. (so now I know the cause of the problem, but I can't fix it, then I started customizing a new Windows 10 ISO without deleting those keys and all works good )

Comment: If this answer doesn't solve your problem, why accept it, means you will miss out on possible real solutions.

Comment: @Ramhound see the last comment below the registry script, I found the cause of the problem, but I determined that after a reset the Windows registry changes in some way then a restoration of those registry keys will not fix the problem (because the registry changed in the reboot, I don't know in which way), then It will be more than impossible for someone to try find out a fix for this specific issue, its complicated, and as I said, I just started to customize a new ISO to avoid spending more time trying to solve it, so problem solved.

Comment: Anyways if someone find a real solution of course I'll assign the accepted answer to him, but by the moment my own investigation is the more resolutive "solution".

Comment: Well it's confusing what your saying exactly....

Comment: Please check the log located in the Event Viewer (eventvwr.msc) under `Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Apps\Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational` for an entry containing `Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost`. Let me know of your finding.

Answer (score 1):

Try in *Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization ->Personalization*,
to apply a default theme.

[EDIT]

Since this did not work out, here are more things to try :

1. [sfc /scannow](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-sfc-command-run-windows-10-a.html) to see if something is broken
2. A new user profile
3. Booting in Safe mode
4. In the registry key
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`,
   check [NoTrayContextMenu](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960470.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which should be undefined or zero.

Question: Have you set "Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse"?

Comment: I've restored the default theme (Aero) with no effect, also I tried to enable and disable all the visualization effects in the control panel, nothing changes. Thankyou anyways!

Comment: I have added above some more ideas.

Comment: 1. Anything broken. 
2. After creating a new user account the missing contextmenu stills. 
3. In safe mode the problem contextmenu stills missing.
4. The **NoTrayContextMenu** reg value is not defined, anyways I defined it with a value of **0** (or **False**).
Q/A: I didn't activated that feature of the "Ease of Access Center". I also reseted jump lists and did a cache icon deletion. I found in Google that there are a lot of people who faces the same issue like me, so maybe this is a more generic Windows problem than I think, maybe the problem is not about any of the customizations I did.

Comment: Under normal conditions I would recommend [Repair Install](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), but this might lose your customizations. You could still try it on a copy of the VM.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty reward for your patience and perseverance helping others and me. thanks again and see you :).

Comment: I would have preferred solving your problem, As a general note: One should use the mechanisms built into Windows to reduce its size. Manual delete is dangerous, and the few megabytes that are saved are not worth the time later spent on analyzing the problems. You can find useful tools by googling for "windows 10 slim", such as using PowerShell to uninstall packages and [NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/263615) is an article you should check.

Summed up:

**No Shortcut Menu Is Displayed When You Right-Click the Taskbar**

To resolve this problem, use the following steps:
Click Start, point to Settings, point to Control Panel, and then click Taskbar and Start Menu.

NOTE: If the Taskbar and Start Menu icon is not present, open Control Panel and click the view all Control Panel options link on the left-hand side of the Control Panel dialog box.

On the Advanced tab, in the Start menu and Taskbar area, scroll down the list until you see the Taskbar heading.

Click to select the Display shortcut menu on right-click check box, click Apply, and then click OK.

Comment: I don't have an "Advanced" tab in the taskbar properties menu as mentioned in that article, thankyou anyways!